# Help needed for airflows animations in Blender without using physics

Tags: animation

Here are the kind of animations I would like to have a training for, in Blender.
I would like to make airflows similar to those seen in the attached images: simple airflows, airflows with arrows inside, multibranch airflows.
You can see the original animations at:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L24Wf0VlTE0
- timestamp: 3:18-3:27
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZLbTuBDhJg&t=929s
- timestamp: 10:29-11:00 and 11:40-12:06

Best Regards

Comment: Please show some screenshots of the animation. Also in order to timestamp a Youtube video you just need to add #t=3m18s at the end of the URL

Answer (score 1):

For the first animation, you can mix a *Diffuse* node (or an *Emission* node) with a *Transparent*, with a *Noise Texture* as factor, then animate the *Mapping* location values, also select the *4D* mode of the *Noise* so that you can keyframe its *W* value and change the shape of the smoke through time:

[image]

[image]

For the second, use the same setup except put a second Mix Shader with an *Input > Layer Weight (Face mode)* as factor with a *Transparent*, so that the smoke comes only on the periphery of the pipe:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank @moonboots for your answer. Actually I do combine Blender with Verge3D and for some reason, the animation as produced the way you generously advised is not rendered in Verge3D. Thank you again.

Comment: Ok sorry I don't know Verge3D so I can't help you  ;)